# Why doesn't CORS work in a simple Express app

Tags: express, cors, es6-modules

I am unable to get rid of this browser error in my sample React/Express app:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9000/getFiles' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Where /getFiles makes an API call from React to Express.

I've done a bunch of googling and I thought I have everything coded correctly.

**App.js**:

```
import express from 'express'; 
import routes  from './routes/index.js'
import cors from "cors";

const app = express(); 
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", routes);

const PORT = 9000; 
  
app.listen(PORT,() => { 
    console.log(`Running on PORT ${PORT}`); 
})
```

I had suspected that it was related to the ES6 formatting but I've seen other code examples that use that import statement exactly as is.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an answer, not a question. I should instead be rewritten as a question, and then the **Post Your Answer** form/button can be used for posted this existing information as a separate answer.

Comment: After a day or so you can accept your own answer; that will show the question as answered in the UI, and will show that answer if people search for the same question.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, I've changed my post to a question but it was not reopened.  Should I create a new post. Thanks and cheers.

Comment: @DouglasBurrill It looks like the post has been reopened now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The issue is because I incorrectly added the cors() reference AFTER setting the routes.  After reversing the order and restarting my app, it started working.

Correct order:

```
...
app.use("/", routes);
app.use(cors());
...
```

Props to [this](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-react-express/) article for putting me on the right track.